# Simplifying Equation - Quantum String

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, tensor-calculus

In this post [Quantum String action](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591608/quantum-string-action) , the user does the following manipulation :

$$\delta (H_{mnp})H^{mnp} =\partial_m\delta(B_{np})[H^{mnp}+H^{pmn}+H^{npm}] $$

I can't quite understand how he does that, I get where the derivative comes from but how does it appear three combinations of $H^{mnp}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $H_{mnp}=\partial_m B_{np}+\partial_n B_{pm}+\partial_p B_{mn}$, then

$$\delta(H_{mnp})=\partial_m(\delta B_{np})+\partial_n(\delta B_{pm})+\partial_p(\delta B_{mn})$$

and

\begin{align}
\delta (H_{mnp})H^{mnp} &=\left[\partial_m(\delta B_{np})+\partial_n(\delta B_{pm})+\partial_p(\delta B_{mn})\right]H^{mnp}\\
&=\partial_m(\delta B_{np})H^{mnp}+\partial_n(\delta B_{pm})H^{mnp}+\partial_p(\delta B_{mn})H^{mnp}\\
&=\partial_m(\delta B_{np})H^{mnp}+\partial_m(\delta B_{np})H^{pmn}+\partial_m(\delta B_{np})H^{npm}\\
&=\partial_m(\delta B_{np})\left[H^{mnp}+H^{pmn}+H^{npm}\right].
\end{align}

So it's just a matter of renaming indices in the last two terms.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!