# First order quantum string action

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, string-theory, action

Considering this post: [Quantum String action](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/591608/quantum-string-action) the action given is of the lowest order but the effective action, for low energies, is given by:

$$ S_{ef.}= -\frac{1}{2k^2} \left( S^{(0)}+ \alpha S^{(1)} + \alpha^2 S^{(2)}+... \right)$$

where $S^{(0)}$ , $S^{(1)}$ , $S^{(2)}$ ,...etc are operators of increasing dimension that envolve the product of the massless fields ($G_{MN}$ and $B_{MN}$)  and their derivatives.
Considering $S^{(1)}$ and that $H_{MNP}=0$,  I was told that we should expect to have $9$ terms and that the Lagrangean density for this case is of the form:

$$ \mathfrak{L}=c e^{m \phi} \left[... \right] $$

I'm having trouble figuring out what these terms are (they are supposed to appear in those parenthesis above but I dont know what they are) and why are there $9$ of them.